# MySQL SUM Cash Value by Category (JOIN)

Tags: mysql

I want to display expenditure data per category. I have two table-striped, notes and category
notes table:

```
id | title | amount | type | cID
 1 | Some ... | 50 | out | 1
 2 | Some ... | 25 | out | 1
 3 | Some ... | 20 | out | 2
 4 | Some ... | 75 | out | 1
 5 | Some ... | 50 | out | 2
```

Category table:

```
id | cID | cName
 1 | 1 | Home
 2 | 2 | School
```

I want to display like this:
Home: $ 150
School: $ 70

My query:

> SELECT SUM(amount) from notes n
>     Join category c
>   On n.cID = c.CID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by category name:

```
SELECT concat(c.cname,  ': $', SUM(n.amount)) totals
from notes n Join category c On n.cID = c.CID
GROUP BY c.cname
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6nL9psTdLKXW667yK9BtgU/1)

Comment: Oke fine. I only must add group by